# JS to handle failed basic authentication of request and don't show pop-up in browser for requiring credentials

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch, basic-authentication, bearer-token

I'm looking for a code snippet that handles an ajax fetch error with basic authentication and disallowing a browser to not show authentication pop-up.

I was getting bearer token from the api endpoint and it happened to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's function I was using.

I've created a code which meets my requirements.

```
async function getBearerToken(params) {
    var appID = params.appID;
    var appSecret = params.appSecret;
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(appID + ":" + appSecret));
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        credentials:'omit' //use this to stop browser-popup asking for basic auth credentials.
    };
    return fetch("<url-here>", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            return result;
        })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); return false; });
}

result = await getBearerToken({appID:"<app-id>",appSecret:"<app-secret>"});
```

I've created it such a way that you can directly check in the console right away!

Hoping you've got your problem solved if you faced it as I did!